# Show that $\left| N \cap Z(G) \right| > 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a non-trivial $p$-group, let $Z(G)$ denote its center, and let $N$ be a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$. Show that $\left| N \cap Z(G) \right| > 1.$

Proof. Let $a \ast n = C_a(n) = ana^{-1}$ for $a \in G$ and $n \in N$. Since $1 \ast n = C_1(n) = n$ for all $n \in N$ and $a \ast (b \ast n) = C_a(C_b(n)) = (C_a \circ C_b)(n)   = C_a(bnb^{-1}) = abnb^{-1}a^{-1} = abn(ab)^{-1} = C_{ab}(n) = (ab) \ast n.$

It follows that $\ast$ is an action of $G$ on $N$ by conjugation. Let $N^G$ denote the set of $G$-fixed points and note that $N^G  = N \cap Z(G)$ (Since the elements that commute with $G$ are invariant under conjugation). Thus, we obtain $| Z(G) \cap N | \equiv | N | \equiv 0 \mod p$. This implies that $p$ divides $| Z(G) \cap N |$, and so $|Z(G) \cap N| \geqslant p > 1$.

Edit:
$| Z(G) \cap N | \equiv | N |$ is a result of the following corollary:

> Let $G$ be a $p$-group and let $X$ be a finite $G$-set. Then $|X^G| \equiv |X| \mod p$.

One has $| N | \equiv 0 \mod p$, since $G$ and $N$ are $p$-groups and so have orders equal to some power of $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to require nontriviality of $G$ when you already require it for $N$.

You use $C_a \circ C_b = C_{ab}$; this needs to be proven (easy at it is, but you are explicitly proving easier things).

Explicit is better than implicit: "$*$ is an action of $G$ on $N$ (by conjugation)" instead of "$G$ acts on $N$ by conjugation".

Each $X$ should be $N$.

How do you get $\left|Z(G) \cap N \right| \equiv \left|X\right| \equiv \left|G\right| \equiv 0 \mod p$? I also think the $\left|G\right|$ term shouldn't be there.

Other than this, yes, it's the right proof.

Comment: I made some changes, let me know what you think.

Comment: Very good -- but drop the $\left|G\right|$; you never use it.